# Align text with toggle switch

Tags: html, css

I followed instructions of w3schools to create a [html toggle switch](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp) and I want text to be on the left of it to explain what the slider does but it keeps being put on top of the slider or miss aligned.

```css
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked+.slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

```html
<form class="options">
    <div id="enabled">
        <p>Enabled</p>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

the text is in the p tag and the switch in the label.
I have tried removing display inline-block but it caused it to not look right.

Comment: add `display: inline-block;` to `p` and `vertical-align: middle;` to `.switch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` to the `#enabled div` and maybe some margin for spacing.

More about Flexbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: It worked! thanks. https://codepen.io/nonhacker/pen/abpQeBo

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to put the `display` property of your `<p>` tag to `inline-block` and `vertical-align` to `middle`. Thus, with a bit of padding to your paragraph, you can center it with your switch button.

```css
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
}

p {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-right:5px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked+.slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

```html
<form class="options">
    <div id="enabled">
        <p>Enabled</p>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```